# how to take advantage of Java vulnerable code if class is not final, allows to be cloned etc

Tags: java, security, secure-coding

I don´t know if I'm not seeing something obvious... I was reading these recommendations for secure coding: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076837/mobile-java/twelve-rules-for-developing-more-secure-java-code.html

if we don't declare classes  or methods final, they could be overridden or extended in the byte code by an attacker, so he can place malicious code of his own in the bytecode, but I don't see clearly how the attack can be completed. I mean, how to make the program use the extended class instead of the original one... for instance if we have a program:

```
public class TheClass {
    public void someAction(char[] userPassword) {
        //some action
    }
}

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TheClass theClass=new TheClass();
        theClass.someAction(readPasswordFromUserInput());
    }
}
```

and the attacker creates another malicious class :

```
public class TheMaliciousClass extends TheClass{
    public void someAction(char[] userPassword) {
        //some action
        //some malicious action
        //send password to attacker's website
    }
}
```

How to trick the program, user or whatever you need to trick so the program uses TheMaliciousClass instead of TheClass? Maybe I did not get the point right and the attack is done in other way...Anyway, I'd appreciate any explanation. Thanks a lot!!

in OWASP they also talk about this security flaw in "finiality": https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Java_leading_security_practice

Answer (score 1):

That article is from 1998.  I'm a bit suspicious of some of those rules.  You are much better off following something like [CERT Java Secure Coding Guidelines](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/Java+Coding+Guidelines) which clearly explain the vulnerability in each rule and the correct fix.

UPDATE:
The problem is that your original source and the one you added in the comments are making vague generalizations.  The source you referenced in the comments says "make classes final unless you have a good reason not to" (i.e. there are legitimate reasons to make a class non-final).  And, there's no way that a static analysis tool is going to understand that "this class should be extensible" and "this class should not be extensible".

Basically, your question gets at the root of the problem.  If you control the way that the class is instantiated and used, how can the fact that the attacker can extend the class change anything?  As you deduced, they can't!  If the attacker can instantiate the class on their own and then pass it into your sensitive application code, then it could be a problem.

On top of all this, you need to understand that these recommendations only apply in certain situations.  If the attacker doesn't have direct access to the running code, then this recommendation is irrelevant to you (e.g. if you are writing a web application).  If the attacker has physical access to the running code, then everything else is probably irrelevant, because they can do whatever they want with the jvm.  The only time this extensibility recommendation would even make sense is in an application where you are allowing third parties to inject code into the running application and your application is running under a SecurityManager.  If that's not your situation, then you can ignore this recommendation.

Ultimately, many of the security recommendations are nuanced, and you have to understand the problem in order to make reasonable decisions about your code.  And for these nuanced recommendations, static analysis is not going to do much other than alert you to the fact that there's a class you need to think about.

Comment: Thanks for the link.. I  ran an updated static code analysis tool, and it marked all classes no declared as final as very risky.  Besides I have read many articles that state the same, like this one in the OWASP https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Java_leading_security_practice (2010). Besides Gary Mcgraw is a very important figure in security, and nowhere appears that java fixed that in some way...

Comment: @Samuel - added some more context.